# Error while creating a Register Form using UserManager and SignInManager in an ASP.NET core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to create a register form using UserManager and SignInManager, however I am stuck with an error.

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'
>   while attempting to activate
>   'ProjectApplicationX00140684.Controllers.AccountController'.

Here is my AccountController:

```cs
namespace ProjectApplicationX00140684.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager;

        public AccountController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(Register model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Copy data from RegisterViewModel to IdentityUser
                var user = new IdentityUser
                {
                    UserName = model.Email,
                    Email = model.Email
                };

                // Store user data in AspNetUsers database table
                var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

                // If user is successfully created, sign-in the user using
                // SignInManager and redirect to index action of HomeController
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                    return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
                }

                // If there are any errors, add them to the ModelState object
                // which will be displayed by the validation summary tag helper
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Startup.cs

```cs
namespace ProjectApplicationX00140684
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {


            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<VehicleContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should configure Identity services , services are added in `ConfigureServices` method :

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
    .AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

ApplicationDbContext.cs:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

And add authentication middleware to the request pipeline:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

After that you can apply migrations(Update-Database) to update database 
Please refer to document for more details and code sample :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest you use the authentication template available when starting a new project. Check the authentication checkbox in the project wizard and then choose the individual in app option.

This will sort out all of the setup for you and add a partial for the login state.

You can then add a model class that inherits from identity in order to add your own custom fields if that’s necessary.

If you’re using a SPA like angular or react, there are templates that include the authentication for that as well.